# Loop through rows and check particular value

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Currently the below command checks the number of GREEN rows is greater than 2  and exits. Instead of that could you please suggest better way to check if all rows are GREEN and should exit afterwards.

```
while true ; do status=`sapcontrol -nr ${INST_NUM} -function GetProcessList |awk -F ',' '{if ($3) print $3;}'|grep -i GREEN | wc -l`; if [[ $status -ge 2 ]]; then break ;fi; done
```

Thanks,
Anup

Comment: Could you please do show us that if your command `sapcontrol` is running in a loop or reading a file? Or its just running a single time? Kindly confirm once

Comment: You should provide examples of what the `sapcontrol` output looks like.

Comment: sapcontrol output command looks as below 
sapcontrol -nr ${INST_NUM} -function GetProcessList 
18.12.2019 02:55:15 
GetProcessList
 OK 
name, description, dispstatus, textstatus, starttime, elapsedtime, pid disp+work, Dispatcher, GREEN, Running, 2019 12 17 04:22:48, 22:32:27, 49847 igswd_mt, IGS Watchdog, GREEN, Running, 2019 12 17 04:22:48, 22:32:27, 49848 gwrd, Gateway, GREEN, Running, 2019 12 17 04:22:49, 22:32:26, 49852 icman, ICM, GREEN, Running, 2019 12 17 04:22:49, 22:32:26, 49853

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want field 3 of all lines that have the field to contain "GREEN"? You can just check this directly in Awk:

```
while ! sapcontrol -nr ${INST_NUM} -function GetProcessList | \
      awk -F ',' '$3 && !(tolower($3) ~ /green/) { exit 1 }'
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Of course you could also count the number of "GREEN" lines, but that's unnecessary and harder to maintain when the number of lines changes, if your actual condition is "all must be green". But in case the condition is "at least 2 lines must be green", change the Awk part to:

```
awk -F ',' '$3 && (tolower($3) ~ /green/) { ++green } END { exit (green < 2) }'
```

Note that the comparison will match things like "not green" and "greenish", because they contain the string "green". This is the same as in the question itself, because I suspect that the equality comparison (`tolower($3) == "green"`) may fail with the current field separator, which doesn't ignore spaces between the comma-separated fields. However, currently a sample output of `sapcontrol` hasn't been posted in the question, so I don't know for sure whether the field separator should be, e.g., `,[ \t]*`.

On a related note, I suspect that `sapcontrol` will also output some header lines that will never match "GREEN", and this is why you are counting the matches instead of checking that they are all green. A better solution than counting is to specifically ignore the header lines, e.g., if there is one header line, make the condition `NR > 1 && $3 && …`.

Comment: It's probably okay in this case, but `tolower($3) ~ /green/` will be true if `$3` is the string "not green", so you might want to use `==` or anchors in the regex.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I know, and at first it was `== "green"` but since the OP hasn't shown what the output of `sapcontrol` actually looks like, I edited it to match their current code (which is just checking that it contains green). In particular, I believe the correct field separator is probably `,[ \t]*` or something along those lines, so using the OP's `,` separator will fail the equality comparison if the field is `" GREEN"`.

Comment: @Arkku. sapcontrol output command looks as below
 sapcontrol -nr ${INST_NUM} -function GetProcessList

18.12.2019 02:55:15
GetProcessList
OK
name, description, dispstatus, textstatus, starttime, elapsedtime, pid
disp+work, Dispatcher, GREEN, Running, 2019 12 17 04:22:48, 22:32:27, 49847
igswd_mt, IGS Watchdog, GREEN, Running, 2019 12 17 04:22:48, 22:32:27, 49848
gwrd, Gateway, GREEN, Running, 2019 12 17 04:22:49, 22:32:26, 49852
icman, ICM, GREEN, Running, 2019 12 17 04:22:49, 22:32:26, 49853 .   I separated the fields and checked for GREEN using awk as mentioned earlier.